# How to set that one variable is greater then the other in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a "rock, paper, scissors" game in Python and i want to set one variable to be greater then the other one.

something like:

```py
paper > rock
scissors > paper
rock > scissors
```

how could i do it..?

Comment: Have you tried anything? It is always nice to us if you also show us the code you have tried.

Comment: Note that this kind of thing is generally not a good idea, because you can't create a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) over objects with these relationships. Basically, if you define `>` as you describe, it would break other built-in mechanisms like `sort()` because the ordering is circular.

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes as Daniel said, with the override of `__cmp__` you can acheive this :

```
class Comparable(object):
    def __init__(self, below_class, above_class):
        self.above_class = above_class
        self.below_class = below_class

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.below_class):
            return 1
        if isinstance(other, self.above_class):
            return -1
        return 0

class Paper(Comparable):
    pass

class Rock(Comparable):
    pass

class Scissors(Comparable):
    pass

scissors = Scissors(Paper, Rock)
paper = Paper(Rock, Scissors)
rock = Rock(Scissors, Paper)

# True

print paper > rock
print scissors > paper
print rock > scissors

# False

print paper < rock
print scissors < paper
print rock < scissors
```

The documentation on the way this works is available here : [https://docs.python.org/2.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.**cmp**](https://docs.python.org/2.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__)

Comment: could you explain this `class Paper(Comparable):
    pass

class Rock(Comparable):
    pass

class Scissors(Comparable):
    pass`

Comment: @ikuro those simply generate 3 subclasses of `Comparable` that aren't really different from `Comparable` except they have different types. Because they have different types you can compare the types as done in `__cmp__`.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually an interesting question, because it raises some useful ideas.

If, for example, paper-rock-scissors followed the laws of [mathematical inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)) it would be a trivial problem. Let's say `paper > rock > scissors` is *mathematically* true (i.e. `paper > scissors`, contrary to the rules of the game):

```
class fist(object):

   def __init__(self, weapon):
       WEAPON_VALUES = {'paper': 2, 'rock': 1, 'scissors': 0}
       self.weapon_value = WEAPON_VALUES[weapon]

   def __gt__(self, other):
       return self.weapon_value > other.weapon_value

   def __lt__(self, other):
       return self.weapon_value < other.weapon_value

   def __eq__(self, other):
       return self.weapon_value == other.weapon_value

   def __ne__(self, other):
       return self.weapon_value != other.weapon_value    

paper = fist('paper')

rock = fist('rock')

scissors = fist('scissors')
```

Now we can check:

```
In [7]: paper > rock
Out[7]: True

In [8]: rock == rock
Out[8]: True

In [9]: paper < scissors
Out[9]: False

In [10]: scissors < rock
Out[10]: True
```

Unfortunately, paper-rock-scissors has a circular logic, and so the usual concept of inequality doesn't work in this case (hence `paper < scissors` evaluates to `False`).

You could use custom comparables [as explained in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54257103), but bear in mind that this raises paradoxes like `rock > scissors > paper == True` when of course `rock < paper`.

Comment: I don't know why this is getting upvotes, it doesn't solve the problem as given by your own test case: `paper < scissors == False`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes I explained in the answer that this is for an example where paper > rock > scissors is *mathematically* true (i.e. paper > scissors). And then explained why this approach wouldn't be recommended for the actual rules of paper-rock-scissors (inequality paradoxes). But perhaps it's not clear enough - do you have a suggestion for how I could communicate this more clearly?

Comment: The paradox exists for *any* valid solution, I thought that was the best part of your answer. The problem I have is that it fails for some tests that *shouldn't* be paradoxes. I.E. you didn't answer the actual question.

Comment: Sure, I wanted to run through why no solution was a sensible idea, because you break the concept of inequality as it is properly understood. I have now linked to the correct solution, so hopefully this serves as a useful addition to the accepted answer. I do understand your concerns, though. (My implicit answer to the actual question is: "don't do this".)

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest in your case is to create a function that would return the winner. Something like

```
def winner(J1, J2):
    if J1 == 'rock':
        if J2 == 'paper':
            return('J2')
        if J2 == 'rock':
            return('draw')
        if J2 == 'paper':
            return('J1')
    ...
```

That would allow you to see who wins.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the behavior of the `>` operator by defining a `__gt__` method on the object. See the [documentation on the Python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__gt__) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple solution that doesn't involve redefining operators:

First define the rules of the game:

```
rules = ['paper>rock', 'rock>scissors', 'scissors>paper']
```

and use a function like this to check the data against the rules:

```
def greater(opt1, opt2):
    if opt1 == opt2:
        return None # draw
    return "{0}>{1}".format(opt1, opt2) in rules

>>> greater('paper','rock')
True
>>> greater('paper','scissors')
False
>>> greater('rock','paper')
False
```